# Windows 10 remote desktop, switch between single and multiple monitors

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

Is there a way to switch between the multiple monitor view and single monitor view using Microsoft's remote desktop application without disconnecting, switching the display setting and reconnecting?

Comment: With plain RDP, no. But You can do it on the fly with Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Mananger 2.7 Though, I think you still need to reconnect in order for the setting to become effective. So you could in essense make 2 RDP files, with both settings, and connect at will. EDIT: never mind. MS RDCM does not support multiple monitors.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, I just tested this scenario on my setup.  The trick is to **toggle between maximized (full screen) and windowed mode** to change how many monitors are shown in the RDP app.  You can use the maximize button in the upper right corner or just double click on the title bar.  The details of my test went like this:

- started in 2 monitor mode when first connecting RDP with the "use all monitors" ticked.
- disconnected 2nd monitor (tried both disabling second monitor in display settings and disconnecting second monitor physically by switching inputs on an HDMI switch I have my second monitor connected to, both worked)
- maximize the RDP window and you'll get 1 monitor on your RDP session
- reconnect second monitor
- toggle maximize/windowed and the second monitor will reconnect on the RDP session, all without disconnecting the RDP session.

**Maximizing the RDP window seems to be the key to getting your RDP session monitor configuration to match your local monitor configuration.**

EDIT: If you don't want to disconnect your local monitors, you can use RDP in Windowed mode using most of one screen and use the bottom scroll bar to slide between the remote monitors.